# WatchKit Error with "no symbols for paired Apple watch" watchOS 3.1

Tags: debugging, swift3, xcode8, watchos-3

im trying do develop my app on my watchos3.1 and i getting every time this error.

```
no symbols for paired Apple watch
```

Xcode doesn't download the latest symbols for my watchOS 3.1. In my folde

```
Library->Developer->Xcode->watchOS DeviceSupport->
```

i only find a file with "watch1,2 3.0"

how can i download the file with 3.1 ?

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this issue with Xcode 9 and watchOS 4. It turned out that I was not logged in anymore to my Apple ID in Xcode. Go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` and log into your account. Then disconnect and reconnect the iPhone with the paired watch and Xcode should now be able to download the symbol files.

Comment: Finally, the correct solution to this problem which has plagued me for months!

Comment: Still the correct solution with Xcode 12 and watchOS 7.3

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Saved me so much trouble, I don't get why you don't get a more detailed error message about the not being logged in

Answer (score 2):

In my case this happened because there was a new license agreement pending in my account. After I had accepted the new agreement, Xcode was able to download necessary symbols

Comment: This worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my watch app working by installing the app to my phone first (without the watch component), and then installing the watchOS app directly from my phone's Watch app.

This is a bit of a work-around, but I too could not find the 3.1 file anywhere.

Comment: but in your solution u can't debug the app ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended up deleting the app from my phone and watch, closing Xcode, and trying to install it again. After a few attempts this ended up working. I would also double check that you're running the latest version of XCode. Hope you get it resolved!